# Passing down arguments

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a common argument splitter due to the nature of my js class. I cannot figure out how to `apply`, or `call`, this functin and pass the `arguments` object without actually passing it as an argument of the function.

```
function splitArgs(){
   return {
       text : arguments[0],
       class : arguments[1] || ""  
   }
}

function doSomething(){
    var args = splitArgs.call(this, arguments);
    if(args.class)
      // do stuff
}
```

I have tried

`splitArgs.call(this, arguments);`

`splitArgs.call(this, ...arguments);`

`splitArgs.apply(this, arguments);`

`splitArgs.apply(this, ...arguments);`

`splitArgs(...arguments);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you say you tried `splitArgs.apply(this, arguments)`... but it seems to work for me:

```js
function splitArgs() {
   return {
       text: arguments[0],
       class: arguments[1] || ""  
   };
}

function doSomething() {
    var args = splitArgs.apply(this, arguments);
    console.log(args);
}

doSomething('foo', 'bar');

// Output:
// { text: 'foo', class: 'bar' }
```

Output:

```
{ text: 'foo', class: 'bar' }
```

With ES6, this also works for me:

```
var args = splitArgs(...arguments);
```

Comment: Your fiddle works fine for me. (I did `new Foo().do("foo", "bar")`, and then both worked.) **EDIT**: This was a response to a since-deleted comment.

Comment: thx. i had some more argument issues higher up that were putting all arguments into the first argument!